# AS3 - Convert Tiff to png

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, png, tiff

I'm trying to use AS3 to convert a Tiff file into a PNG file.

```
var bytes:ByteArray = img.data as ByteArray;
var tiffDecoder:TIFF6Decoder = new TIFF6Decoder();

var pngSync:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();

if( tiffDecoder.decode(bytes) ) 
{
    var bytesPNG:ByteArray = pngSync.encode(tiffDecoder.bitmapData);
    var tmp:File = File.createTempDirectory();
    img = FileUtils.writeFile(bytesPNG, tmp.nativePath + "/image.png");
}
else { Alert.show("Failed TIFF decoding"); }
```

But an error appears from the decode function.

Do you know another solution to do that?
 PHP's ImageMagik may be a considered solution but I need to have the same installation on Windows and MacOS.

Comment: This isn't PHP, why is PHP tagged?

Comment: Because, I'd like to found a solution with AS3 or PHP

Comment: So, now we should guess what error did you get, what source TIFF you used, what library did you use as decoder... right?

Comment: ImageMagick is available on all patforms. IMagick is the PHP wrapper class.

Comment: It's not my question!

Comment: @Flex60460 since only a `Bitmap`object has bitmap data why would your decoder give `tiffDecoder.bitmapData`? Show us the `function decode( xxx:ByteArray)` from your decoder Class. Or explain if it returns bitmap data or simply updates a type bitmapdata variable within the class itself?

Comment: @delboy1978uk Oops sorry!! Fixed now by addressing the correct person.